# Procedure or function 'spDelRegistrant' expects parameter '@RegistrantId', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I reference a GridView id and set it equal to my parameter id?

I am doing a delete and when I hit delete I get this error:

> Procedure or function 'spDelRegistrant' expects parameter
>   '@RegistrantId', which was not supplied.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RegistrantId" HeaderText="RegistrantId" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RegistrantId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EventId" HeaderText="EventId" 
                    SortExpression="EventId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FormId" HeaderText="FormId" 
                    SortExpression="FormId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RequesterId" HeaderText="RequesterId" 
                    SortExpression="RequesterId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentId" HeaderText="PaymentId" 
                    SortExpression="PaymentId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomFieldId" HeaderText="CustomFieldId" 
                    SortExpression="CustomFieldId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DistrictId" HeaderText="DistrictId" 
                    SortExpression="DistrictId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalNumberId" HeaderText="LocalNumberId" 
                    SortExpression="LocalNumberId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TitleId" HeaderText="TitleId" 
                    SortExpression="TitleId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IndustryId" HeaderText="IndustryId" 
                    SortExpression="IndustryId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateCreated" HeaderText="DateCreated" 
                    SortExpression="DateCreated" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateLastModified" HeaderText="DateLastModified" 
                    SortExpression="DateLastModified" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="CreatedBy" 
                    SortExpression="CreatedBy" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedBy" HeaderText="ModifiedBy" 
                    SortExpression="ModifiedBy" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AddressLine1" HeaderText="AddressLine1" 
                    SortExpression="AddressLine1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AddressLine2" HeaderText="AddressLine2" 
                    SortExpression="AddressLine2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Zip" HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="Zip" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
                    SortExpression="Country" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneExt" HeaderText="PhoneExt" 
                    SortExpression="PhoneExt" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Employer" HeaderText="Employer" 
                    SortExpression="Employer" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberId" HeaderText="MemberId" 
                    SortExpression="MemberId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" 
                    SortExpression="Comments" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalUnionEmail" HeaderText="LocalUnionEmail" 
                    SortExpression="LocalUnionEmail" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByFirstName" 
                    HeaderText="CompletedByFirstName" SortExpression="CompletedByFirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByLastName" 
                    HeaderText="CompletedByLastName" SortExpression="CompletedByLastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByPhone" HeaderText="CompletedByPhone" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByPhone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" 
                    SortExpression="Position" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShirtSize" HeaderText="ShirtSize" 
                    SortExpression="ShirtSize" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
            DeleteCommand="spDelRegistrant" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            SelectCommand="spGetAllRegistrants" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory, your Stored Procedure `spDelRegistrant` expects a parameter `@RegistrantId` which was not supplied by your code. So in your SQL Datasource control include the delete parameter like this:-

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
            DeleteCommand="spDelRegistrant" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            SelectCommand="spGetAllRegistrants" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
   <DeleteParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="RegistrantId" Type="Int32" />
   </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Next, you will have to set the `DataKeyNames` property in your gridview to specify which RegistrantId it should take:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="RegistrantId"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I wasn't sure of the structure. :)